# Android dev: Sync database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is my first time writing an Android app that utilizes a database.

I have created a test database in the assets folder. I then have the app copy the database to the database folder: /data/data/myapplication1/databases/myDB.db

I realize now that the assets folders are read only, but how can I sync my database so I can verify, using SQLite browser, the changes I have made?

Should I just move my test DB from assets to a different location? Is there something better?

Or is there a way I can view the DB in the databases folder? (which I believe is protected so it is not visible to other programs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to view the database from the databases folder:

1. with `adb` on either a rooted device or an emulator, just `adb pull /data/data/myapplication/databases/mydb.db`.
2. with `adb` on a non-rooted/non-emulator, you can try `adb shell "run-as [package.name.myapplication] cp /data/data/myapplication/databases/mydb.db /sdcard/mydb.db"`, and then `adb pull /sdcard/mydb.db`.
3. if you integrate [stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) in your app, you can easily inspect sqlite databases from chrome.